# How can I work with a form, that uses a model, which has 2 foreign keys? Automatically updating author and linking form to database

Tags: django, django-forms

New to django.
Currently have 2 problems with one form.

1. I created a form from the model'Submission', in which the user can change the submission
   _author. How can I set it so that django automatically assigns the
   current logged in user to the submission_author(undetiable field type of thing)?
2. Whenever I submit the form, this error pops up      (NOT NULL constraint failed:
   themainpage_submission.post_id), where post_id is taken from the
   Submissions model(linked image). How can this be fixed?

[sceenshot from the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsno5.jpg)

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   post_creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   genre = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, choices= genre_choices)
   stage = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, choices= stage_choice)
   optional_notes = models.CharField(max_length=80, default= 'dummy-text')

   def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('home_view')

   def __str__(self):
      return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)

class Submission(models.Model):
   post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='submissions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   submission_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   submission_title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   submission_creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   submission_body = models.TextField()

   def __str__(self):
          return self.submission_title + ' | ' + self.submission_body
```

**forms.py**

```
class CreateNewSubmission(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Submission
    fields = ('submission_title', 'submission_body', 'submission_author')
```

**urls.py**

```
    path('view_post/<str:pk>', views.ViewPostMain, name='view_post'),
    path('view_post/<str:pk>/create_submission', CreateSubmission.as_view(), name='create_submission'),
```

**views.py**

```
def ViewPostMain(request, pk):
   post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
   submissions = Submission.objects.filter(post_id = pk)
   context = {'post' : post, 'submissions' : submissions}
   return render(request, 'view-post.html', context)

class CreateSubmission(CreateView):
   model = Submission
   template_name = 'create_submission.html'
   form_class = CreateNewSubmission
```

**create_submission.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Create a submission</h1>
    <div class="form-group"> 
    <form method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.media }}
        {{ form.as_p }}     
        <button class="btn btn-secondary">Post</button>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

help. please. im dying

Comment: why do you ever need `Submission` model, what's the point ?

Comment: It would be used later for a user to upload files, which will be displayed to the specified post. Submission is kind of like a comment, but it also would include an audio file